# Affect the element using onfocus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I only affect the element that when I focus on the input type the error message below it should be gone, problem is when I focus on the input type the error message hides all. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

This is my HTML structure

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="form-message">Please all fields  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="form-message">Please all fields  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="form-message">Please all fields  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="form-message">Please all fields</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="form-message">Please all fields </div>
</div>
```

my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.form-control').focus(function(e) {
           if($(e.target).next('.form-message').css('display') == 'block'){ 
                    $('.form-message').hide();          
         }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.form-control').focus(function(e) {
         var formMessage = $(e.target).next('.form-message');
         if(formMessage.css('display') == 'block'){ 
               formMessage.hide();
         }
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gveukc0b/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.form-control').focus(function() {
        $(this).next().hide();
 }); 
});
```